# Using the apply function over each column for adjusting of data.frame

Tags: r

So my hope is to change columns 14:18 into 1 column "Type". I wanted to give each of the entries in this new column (for matching observations in the previous) the value of which of the 5 is a 1 (because only 1 of them can be true). This is my best attempt at doing this in R (and beyond frustrated).

```
library(caret)
data("cars")

carSubset <- subset(cars)
head(carSubset)

# I want to convert the columns from of carSubset with following vector names
types <- c("convertible","coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon")

# into 1 column named Type, with the corresponding column name
carSubset$Type <- NULL
carSubset <- apply(carSubset[,types],
               2, 
               function(each_obs){
                   hit_index <- which(each_obs == 1)
                   carSubset$Type <- types[hit_index]
              })
head(carSubset) # output:
  1             2             3             4             5 
  "sedan"       "coupe" "convertible" "convertible" "convertible"
```

Which is what I wanted ... however, I also wanted the rest of my data.frame to come along with it, like I just wanted the new column of "Type" but I cannot even access it with the following line of code...

```
head(carSubset$Type) # output: Error in carSubset$Type : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any help on how to  **Add a new column dynamically while appending previously related data observations to it?**

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out! Probably not the best way to do it, but hey, it works.

```
library(caret)
data("cars")

carSubset <- subset(cars)  
head(carSubset)

# I want to convert the columns from of carSubset with following vector names
types <- c("convertible","coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "wagon")

head(carSubset[,types])
carSubset[,types]
# into 1 column named Type, with the corresponding column name
carSubset$Type <- NULL
newSubset <- c()
newSubset <- apply(carSubset[,types],
               1, 
               function(obs){
                   hit_index <- which(obs == 1)
                   newSubset <- types[hit_index]
              })
newSubset
carSubset$Type <- cbind(Type = newSubset)
head(carSubset[, !(names(carSubset) %in% types)])
```